# Drag and reorder - UICollectionview with sections

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, ios9, xcode7, uicollectionviewlayout

Is that possible to do drag and reorder from one section to another section from collectionview - iOS 9.

Every time am dragging from 1st section to drop at 4th section am getting below crash,

Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimationsWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath,toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath)

        {

        let sequence = ArrayrelatedSequence[sourceIndexPath.section] as! SEQ_Sequence

        relIndexCards = sequence.rel_indexCard

        if relIndexCards.count > 0 {

            ArrayIndexcard = []

            let arr1: NSMutableArray = []

            for item in relIndexCards {

                arr1.addObject(item)
            }

            let descriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "keyP_IndexCard_ID", ascending: false)
            let arrNew:NSArray = arr1.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([descriptor])

            let i = 0
            for item in arrNew
            {
                ArrayIndexcard.insert(item as! NSManagedObject, atIndex: i)
                i+1
            }

        }

        let temp = self.ArrayIndexcard.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.item)

        self.ArrayIndexcard.insert(temp, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.item)


        if islongPressed_Indexcard == true
        {
            islongPressed_Indexcard = false

            let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

            var i = 0

            for update in ArrayIndexcard
            {

                i = i+1

                update.setValue(i, forKey: "keyP_IndexCard_ID")

            }

            do {
                try managedContext.save()

                collectionview_in_outline.reloadData()

            } catch let nserror as NSError {

                print("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }

        }
    }
```

My flow layout code below,

```
 class CustomFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

var longPress: UILongPressGestureRecognizer!
var originalIndexPath: NSIndexPath?
var draggingIndexPath: NSIndexPath?
var draggingView: UIView?
var dragOffset = CGPointZero

override func prepareLayout() {
    super.prepareLayout()

    installGestureRecognizer()
}

func applyDraggingAttributes(attributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
    attributes.alpha = 0
}

override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)
    attributes?.forEach { a in
        if a.indexPath == draggingIndexPath {
            if a.representedElementCategory == .Cell {
                self.applyDraggingAttributes(a)
            }
        }
    }
    return attributes
}

override func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    if let attributes = attributes where indexPath == draggingIndexPath {
        if attributes.representedElementCategory == .Cell {
            applyDraggingAttributes(attributes)
        }
    }
    return attributes
}

func installGestureRecognizer() {
    if longPress == nil {
        longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CustomFlowLayout.handleLongPress(_:)))
        longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.2
        collectionView?.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
    }
}

func handleLongPress(longPress: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {


    let location = longPress.locationInView(collectionView!)
    switch longPress.state {
    case .Began: startDragAtLocation(location)
    case .Changed: updateDragAtLocation(location)
    case .Ended: endDragAtLocation(location)
    default:
        break
    }
}

func startDragAtLocation(location: CGPoint) {
    guard let cv = collectionView else { return }
    guard let indexPath = cv.indexPathForItemAtPoint(location) else { return }
    guard cv.dataSource?.collectionView?(cv, canMoveItemAtIndexPath: indexPath) == true else { return }
    guard let cell = cv.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) else { return }

    originalIndexPath = indexPath
    draggingIndexPath = indexPath
    draggingView = cell.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)
    draggingView!.frame = cell.frame
    cv.addSubview(draggingView!)

    dragOffset = CGPointMake(draggingView!.center.x - location.x, draggingView!.center.y - location.y)

    draggingView?.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: draggingView!.bounds).CGPath
    draggingView?.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    draggingView?.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
    draggingView?.layer.shadowRadius = 10

    invalidateLayout()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.4, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: {
        self.draggingView?.alpha = 0.95
        self.draggingView?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2)
        }, completion: nil)
}

func updateDragAtLocation(location: CGPoint) {
    guard let view = draggingView else { return }
    guard let cv = collectionView else { return }

    view.center = CGPointMake(location.x + dragOffset.x, location.y + dragOffset.y)



    if let newIndexPath = cv.indexPathForItemAtPoint(location) {   
             **cv.moveItemAtIndexPath(draggingIndexPath!, toIndexPath: newIndexPath)**
        draggingIndexPath = newIndexPath

    }
}

func endDragAtLocation(location: CGPoint) {
    guard let dragView = draggingView else { return }
    guard let indexPath = draggingIndexPath else { return }
    guard let cv = collectionView else { return }
    guard let datasource = cv.dataSource else { return }

    let targetCenter = datasource.collectionView(cv, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath).center

    let shadowFade = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "shadowOpacity")
    shadowFade.fromValue = 0.8
    shadowFade.toValue = 0
    shadowFade.duration = 0.4
    dragView.layer.addAnimation(shadowFade, forKey: "shadowFade")

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.4, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: {
        dragView.center = targetCenter
        dragView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

    }) { (completed) in

        if !indexPath.isEqual(self.originalIndexPath!) {
            datasource.collectionView?(cv, moveItemAtIndexPath: self.originalIndexPath!, toIndexPath: indexPath)
        }

        dragView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.draggingIndexPath = nil
        self.draggingView = nil
        self.invalidateLayout()
    }

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("Needtorefresh", object: nil)

    collectionView?.reloadData()

}
```

}

Comment: Is anyone met this issue, please help me to get out of this issue

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### Details

- Xcode 10.2 (10E125), Swift 5

### Links

[Coding for iOS 11: How to drag & drop into collections & tables](https://hackernoon.com/drag-it-drop-it-in-collection-table-ios-11-6bd28795b313)

### Full Sample

> ViewController

```
import UIKit

enum CellModel {
    case simple(text: String)
    case availableToDrop
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var cellIdentifier = "cellIdentifier"
    private lazy var supplementaryViewIdentifier = "supplementaryViewIdentifier"
    private lazy var sections = 10
    private lazy var itemsInSection = 2
    private lazy var numberOfElementsInRow = 3

    private lazy var data: [[CellModel]] = {
        var count = 0
        return (0 ..< sections).map { _ in
            return (0 ..< itemsInSection).map { _ -> CellModel in
                count += 1
                return .simple(text: "cell \(count)")
            }
        }
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let collectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
        collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
        let _numberOfElementsInRow = CGFloat(numberOfElementsInRow)
        let allWidthBetwenCells = _numberOfElementsInRow == 0 ? 0 : collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing*(_numberOfElementsInRow-1)
        let width = (view.frame.width - allWidthBetwenCells)/_numberOfElementsInRow
        collectionViewFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width)
        collectionViewFlowLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 40)

        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewFlowLayout)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true

        collectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        collectionView.register(SupplementaryView.self,
                                forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader,
                                withReuseIdentifier: supplementaryViewIdentifier)

        collectionView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
        collectionView.reorderingCadence = .fast
        collectionView.dropDelegate = self
        collectionView.dragDelegate = self

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate { }
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int { return data.count }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data[section].count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        switch data[indexPath.section][indexPath.item] {
            case .simple(let text):
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
                cell.label?.text = text
                cell.backgroundColor = .gray
                return cell
            case .availableToDrop:
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
                return cell
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: supplementaryViewIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! SupplementaryView
        return headerView
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDragDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
        let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: "\(indexPath)" as NSString)
        let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
        dragItem.localObject = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return [dragItem]
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForAddingTo session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> [UIDragItem] {
        let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: "\(indexPath)" as NSString)
        let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
        dragItem.localObject = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return [dragItem]
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dragSessionWillBegin session: UIDragSession) {
        var itemsToInsert = [IndexPath]()
        (0 ..< data.count).forEach {
            itemsToInsert.append(IndexPath(item: data[$0].count, section: $0))
            data[$0].append(.availableToDrop)
        }
        collectionView.insertItems(at: itemsToInsert)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dragSessionDidEnd session: UIDragSession) {
        var removeItems = [IndexPath]()
        for section in 0..<data.count {
            for item in  0..<data[section].count {
                switch data[section][item] {
                    case .availableToDrop: removeItems.append(IndexPath(item: item, section: section))
                    case .simple: break
                }
            }
        }
        removeItems.forEach { data[$0.section].remove(at: $0.item) }
        collectionView.deleteItems(at: removeItems)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDropDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator) {
        let destinationIndexPath: IndexPath
        if let indexPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath {
            destinationIndexPath = indexPath
        } else {
            let section = collectionView.numberOfSections - 1
            let row = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section)
            destinationIndexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
        }

        switch coordinator.proposal.operation {
            case .move:
                reorderItems(coordinator: coordinator, destinationIndexPath:destinationIndexPath, collectionView: collectionView)
            case .copy:
                copyItems(coordinator: coordinator, destinationIndexPath: destinationIndexPath, collectionView: collectionView)
            default: return
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool { return true }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewDropProposal {
        if collectionView.hasActiveDrag, let destinationIndexPath = destinationIndexPath {
            switch data[destinationIndexPath.section][destinationIndexPath.row] {
                case .simple:
                    return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
                case .availableToDrop:
                    return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertIntoDestinationIndexPath)
            }
        } else { return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .forbidden) }
    }

    private func reorderItems(coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator, destinationIndexPath: IndexPath, collectionView: UICollectionView) {
        let items = coordinator.items
        if  items.count == 1, let item = items.first,
            let sourceIndexPath = item.sourceIndexPath,
            let localObject = item.dragItem.localObject as? CellModel {

            collectionView.performBatchUpdates ({
                data[sourceIndexPath.section].remove(at: sourceIndexPath.item)
                data[destinationIndexPath.section].insert(localObject, at: destinationIndexPath.item)
                collectionView.deleteItems(at: [sourceIndexPath])
                collectionView.insertItems(at: [destinationIndexPath])
            })
        }
    }

    private func copyItems(coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator, destinationIndexPath: IndexPath, collectionView: UICollectionView) {
        collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
            for (index, item) in coordinator.items.enumerated() {
                if let localObject = item.dragItem.localObject as? CellModel {
                    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: destinationIndexPath.row + index, section: destinationIndexPath.section)
                    data[indexPath.section].insert(localObject, at: indexPath.row)
                    indexPaths.append(indexPath)
                }
            }
            collectionView.insertItems(at: indexPaths)
        })
    }
}
```

> Cells

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    weak var label: UILabel?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        clipsToBounds = true
        let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        label.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
        label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = .white
        self.label = label
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        backgroundColor = .white
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        label?.text = nil
        backgroundColor = .white
    }
}

import UIKit

class SupplementaryView: UICollectionReusableView {

    weak var label: UILabel?
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks Vasily, Its giving better hope for me, and I need to update my coredata object too based on this dragging. I have updated my question with my snippet please have a look into this and let me know what should I have to do

Comment: It is rather difficult to help you, using that code. I need full code to fix it. Can you generate full code example? Anyway I will add coredata dictionary to my example..

Comment: Thanks, I will do update my code which is am using layout for this collectionview to drag and reorder

Comment: Thanks Vasily, I have fixed and made it run, but one more functionality am doing now more over similar to this, likely I have to move up/Down my collectionview section is that possible?

Comment: I think yes. Please mark this answer and create new question. I will try to make sample for you. I need to find more information about collectionView (does it has native functional to move sections) or create tableView with collectionView in cell. I think, it is possible to move sections.

Comment: Thanks, But it would be great if it is in the same Collectionview else I have to do rework for this

Comment: I found only the day with tableView with collectionView in cell. Only this way is possible. Do you need the example?

Comment: I need example tableview with its cell should contain collectionview

Comment: it's harder than I thought. After 2 days will be ready. Once more, you need the elements can be moved in sections and sections also can be moved, right?

Comment: Hello) I finished. Can you create new question?

Comment: Hi Vasily :) Great job.... Thanks for your kind support. I too finished the same but the thing is, for me that its reordering like swapping thing. I will add your logic and let you know. Thanks once again

Comment: @VasilyBodnarchuk could you send me that xcode project which you used to make that screenshot from?

Comment: @vetrivel, Can you guide me how to change the layout in each section to Horizontal keeping section as vertical

Comment: @vetrivel Also there is bug in above code... I cannot drop a cell at last location... Or if I move all the cell from one section into other section... I cannot move cell back to empty section

Comment: @VasilyBodnarchuk i need to swap cell not shift cell using CollectionView DragInteraction do you have any idea?

Comment: @VasilyBodnarchuk can you help out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71691569/how-can-we-drag-drop-whole-section-for-collection-view-with-horizontal-flow-la

Answer (score 1):

The idea of @Vasily Bodnarchuk is brilliant,

to move item to the end of each section, by adding an item when dragging

Code Optimization to @Vasily Bodnarchuk's solution.

Use

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator) {
        if let destinationIndexPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath, case UIDropOperation.move = coordinator.proposal.operation{
            reorderItems(coordinator: coordinator, destinationIndexPath:destinationIndexPath, collectionView: collectionView)
        }
    }
```

instead of

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator) {
        let destinationIndexPath: IndexPath
        if let indexPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath {
            destinationIndexPath = indexPath
        } else {
            let section = collectionView.numberOfSections - 1
            let row = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section)
            destinationIndexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
        }

        switch coordinator.proposal.operation {
            case .move:
                reorderItems(coordinator: coordinator, destinationIndexPath:destinationIndexPath, collectionView: collectionView)
            case .copy:
                copyItems(coordinator: coordinator, destinationIndexPath: destinationIndexPath, collectionView: collectionView)
            default: return
        }
    }
```

The `else` won't happen.

because of the `forbidden`  situation

No `destinationIndexPath` , then `forbidden`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewDropProposal {
        if collectionView.hasActiveDrag, let destinationIndexPath = destinationIndexPath {
            switch data[destinationIndexPath.section][destinationIndexPath.row] {
                case .simple:
                    return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
                case .availableToDrop:
                    return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertIntoDestinationIndexPath)
            }
        } else { return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .forbidden) }
    }
```

---

And in the solution scene:

`private func copyItems(coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator, destinationIndexPath: IndexPath, collectionView: UICollectionView)`

could be removed

---

The final simplified version of @Vasily Bodnarchuk's in **Swift 5**:

Controller Part:

```
import UIKit

enum CellModel {
    case simple(text: String)
    case availableToDropAtEnd
}

class SecondController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var cellIdentifier = "cellIdentifier"
    private lazy var supplementaryViewIdentifier = "supplementaryViewIdentifier"
    private lazy var sections = 10
    private lazy var itemsInSection = 2
    private lazy var numberOfElementsInRow = 3

    private lazy var data: [[CellModel]] = {
        var count = 0
        return (0 ..< sections).map { _ in
            return (0 ..< itemsInSection).map { _ -> CellModel in
                count += 1
                return .simple(text: "cell \(count)")
            }
        }
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let collectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
        collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
        let _numberOfElementsInRow = CGFloat(numberOfElementsInRow)
        let allWidthBetwenCells = _numberOfElementsInRow == 0 ? 0 : collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing*(_numberOfElementsInRow-1)
        let width = (view.frame.width - allWidthBetwenCells)/_numberOfElementsInRow
        collectionViewFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width)
        collectionViewFlowLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 40)

        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewFlowLayout)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true

        collectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        collectionView.register(SupplementaryView.self,
                                forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader,
                                withReuseIdentifier: supplementaryViewIdentifier)

        collectionView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
        collectionView.reorderingCadence = .fast
        collectionView.dropDelegate = self
        collectionView.dragDelegate = self

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
}



extension SecondController: UICollectionViewDelegate { }


extension SecondController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data[section].count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        switch data[indexPath.section][indexPath.item] {
            case .simple(let text):
                cell.label?.text = text
                cell.backgroundColor = .gray
            case .availableToDropAtEnd:
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
        }
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: supplementaryViewIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    }
}




extension SecondController: UICollectionViewDragDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
        let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: "\(indexPath)" as NSString)
        let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
        dragItem.localObject = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return [dragItem]
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForAddingTo session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> [UIDragItem] {
        let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: "\(indexPath)" as NSString)
        let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
        dragItem.localObject = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return [dragItem]
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dragSessionWillBegin session: UIDragSession) {
        var itemsToInsert = [IndexPath]()
        (0 ..< data.count).forEach {
            itemsToInsert.append(IndexPath(item: data[$0].count, section: $0))
            data[$0].append(.availableToDropAtEnd)
        }
        collectionView.insertItems(at: itemsToInsert)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dragSessionDidEnd session: UIDragSession) {
        var removeItems = [IndexPath]()
        for section in 0..<data.count {
            for item in  0..<data[section].count {
                switch data[section][item] {
                    case .availableToDropAtEnd:
                        removeItems.append(IndexPath(item: item, section: section))
                    case .simple:
                        break
                }
            }
        }
        removeItems.forEach { data[$0.section].remove(at: $0.item) }
        collectionView.deleteItems(at: removeItems)
    }
    
    
}




extension SecondController: UICollectionViewDropDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator) {
        if let destinationIndexPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath, case UIDropOperation.move = coordinator.proposal.operation{
            reorderItems(coordinator: coordinator, destinationIndexPath:destinationIndexPath, collectionView: collectionView)
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewDropProposal {
        if collectionView.hasActiveDrag, let destinationIndexPath = destinationIndexPath {
           switch data[destinationIndexPath.section][destinationIndexPath.row] {
               case .simple:
                  return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
               case .availableToDropAtEnd:
                  return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertIntoDestinationIndexPath)
           }
         } 
         else { return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .forbidden) }
     }

    
    
    private
    func reorderItems(coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator, destinationIndexPath: IndexPath, collectionView: UICollectionView) {
        let items = coordinator.items
        if items.count == 1, let item = items.first,
            let sourceIndexPath = item.sourceIndexPath,
            let localObject = item.dragItem.localObject as? CellModel {

            collectionView.performBatchUpdates ({
                data[sourceIndexPath.section].remove(at: sourceIndexPath.item)
                data[destinationIndexPath.section].insert(localObject, at: destinationIndexPath.item)
                collectionView.deleteItems(at: [sourceIndexPath])
                collectionView.insertItems(at: [destinationIndexPath])
            })
        }
    }

   
}
```

Cell Part:

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    weak var label: UILabel?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        clipsToBounds = true
        let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        label.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
        label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = .white
        self.label = label
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        label?.text = nil
    }
}



class SupplementaryView: UICollectionReusableView {
    
      override init(frame: CGRect) {
          super.init(frame: frame)
          backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
      }

      required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
          super.init(coder: aDecoder)
      }
}
```