# Two different cells in a collectionview?

Tags: swift, swift5

I am working in the Xcode, and I am new in swift.
Can I create two different cells in a collectionview and and be able to move them between each other?

Comment: A quick search on this platform came up with this result: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39088025/1195661.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do from storyboard.

Go to `Main.Storyboard` and select that `CollectionView`. Click on Top right side and select 4th option and increase 'items'. Then your items in collection view will increase.