# Drop Item into an empty Collection View secion

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview, uicollectionviewdropdelegate, uicollectionviewdragdelegate

I'm working with UICollectionView and Drag/Drop Delegates. I need to drop a data source's item into an empty section. I've learned about that and I found out that it's a long-ongoing trouble (e.g. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/114010). But I noticed potential solution in iOS Messages on iOS 15:

[image]

I tried to do similar placeholder but I don't which class it is. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the solution according to Apple forum above? `create an empty cell, not visible, in each section`

Comment: No, I haven't. Do you think it can be an empty cell (according to attched picture)?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39080807/drag-and-reorder-uicollectionview-with-sections

Comment: According to the link, I do likwise but my app creates an 'empty cell' only in the first section during dragging. Thanks.

Comment: I've ended up with my own solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77380175/2265618